# Is it possible to block execution of a trigger if the transition isn't valid?

Tags: python, state-machine, pytransitions

It appears the trigger methods still run then raise the MachineError exception afterwards when transition is not valid from current state. Is there a way to block the execution of a trigger so that a call to the trigger on the model will simply raise the exception and not execute the trigger?

Sorry, forgot to mention using the overridden `_checked_assignment` from the FAQ which may be reason for this behavior.

```
from transitions import State, Machine

class StateMachine(Machine):

    def _checked_assignment(self, model, name, func):
        if hasattr(model, name):
            predefined_func = getattr(model, name)
            def nested_func(*args, **kwargs):
                predefined_func()
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(model, name, nested_func)
        else:
            setattr(model, name, func)

class Rocket(StateMachine):
    def __init__():
        StateMachine.__init__(
            self,
            states=["on_pad", "fueling", "ready", "launched", "meco", "second_stage", "orbit"],
            transitions=[
                {'trigger': 'fuel', 'source': 'on_pad', 'dest': 'fueling'},
                {'trigger': 'power_on', 'source': 'fueling', 'dest': 'ready'},
                {'trigger': 'launch', 'source': 'ready', 'dest': 'launched'}
            ],
            initial='on_pad'
        )

    def fuel():
        print("cryos loading...")

    def launch():
        print("launching")

def main():
    rocket = Rocket()
    rocket.launch()  # prints "launching" then throws Machine Error, need to block actual method execution
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example for your issue? The 'trigger' includes the check whether a transition is valid or not from the current state but will not process the actual transition.

Comment: Added example. Apologies, forgot to mention using the overriden `_checked_assignment` from FAQ which I believe is the reason for the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could wrap your callbacks with an override of `Machine._checked_assignment` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198767/1617563) answer, I'd recommend tying methods that should be called in the context of a transition to its callbacks. Callbacks can be called on multiple occasions during a transition as described in the documentation's chapter [Callback execution order](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#callback-execution-order). The caveat is that callbacks must not have the same name as intended triggers but this is usually a minor setback and also enables you to add multiple callbacks to the same event. I reworked your example a bit. `Rocket` acts as the stateful model but the machine itself has been separated. You could also manage the state machine completely independently of your `Rocket` in case you plan to use multiple instances. One machine can handle multiple stateful objects. Furthermore, I renamed your callbacks slightly and passed them to the `before` keyword of the transitions. As mentioned earlier, this could also be a list (`{'before': ['on_launch']}` is also valid). This way, they will be called right before the transition will happen and will not be called when a) `Rocket` is not in the correct state or b) condition checks for the transition in question failed.

```py
from transitions import Machine, MachineError


class Rocket:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(
            self,
            states=["on_pad", "fueling", "ready", "launched", "meco", "second_stage", "orbit"],
            transitions=[
                {'trigger': 'fuel', 'source': 'on_pad', 'dest': 'fueling', 'before': 'on_fueling'},
                {'trigger': 'power_on', 'source': 'fueling', 'dest': 'ready'},
                {'trigger': 'launch', 'source': 'ready', 'dest': 'launched', 'before': 'on_launch'}
            ],
            initial='on_pad'
        )

    def on_fueling(self):
        print("cryos loading...")

    def on_launch(self):
        print("launching")


rocket = Rocket()
try:
    rocket.launch()
    assert False
except MachineError:
    pass

rocket.fuel()  # >>> cryos loading...
rocket.power_on() 
rocket.launch()  # >>> launching
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue as I typed out the example, need to call the passed in func() prior to predefined_func() within `_checked_assignment`. This method should be updated on the [FAQ](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/blob/master/examples/Frequently%20asked%20questions.ipynb) to retain original transition functionality.

```
    def _checked_assignment(self, model, name, func):
        if hasattr(model, name):
            predefined_func = getattr(model, name)
            def nested_func(*args, **kwargs):
                func(*args, **kwargs)  # need to call before pre-defined
                predefined_func()
            setattr(model, name, nested_func)
        else:
            setattr(model, name, func)
```